# Original audio of tab gets muted while using chrome.tabCapture.capture() and MediaRecorder()

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

when i use chrome.tabCapture.capture() with MediaRecorder API to record stream  original audio of tabs which i am capturing gets muted but the audio comes OK in recorded stream, i want the audio in the tab to run normally  ....

```
class Recorder {
  constructor(onChunksAvailable) {
    this.chunks = [];

    this.active = false;

    this.callback = onChunksAvailable;
  }

  start(stream) {
    if (this.active) {
      throw new Error("recorder is already running");
    }
    this.recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, {
      mimeType: "audio/webm",
    });

    this.recorder.onstop = () => {
      stream.getAudioTracks()[0].stop();
      this.callback([...this.chunks]);

      setTimeout(() => {
        this.chunks = [];
      });

      this.active = false;
    };

    this.recorder.ondataavailable = (event) => this.chunks.push(event.data);

    this.active = true;
    this.recorder.start();
  }

  stop() {
    if (!this.active) {
      throw new Error("recorder is already stop");
    } else {
      this.recorder.stop();
    }
  }
}

let rec = new Recorder(async (chunks) => {
//using chunks then to get the stream
});

chrome.tabCapture.capture(
    {
      audio: true,
      video: false,
    },
    function (stream) {
        rec.start(stream);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Forgive me for lack of documentation as I last played with these APIs years ago, but [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamAudioSourceNode) has some stuff.

In my case adding these 3 lines to the start function was fixed.

```js
this.context = new AudioContext();
this.stream = this.context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
this.stream.connect(this.context.destination);
```

```js
class Recorder {
  constructor(onChunksAvailable) {
    this.chunks = [];

    this.active = false;

    this.callback = onChunksAvailable;

    this.context = new AudioContext();
  }

  start(stream) {
    if (this.active) {
      throw new Error("recorder is already running");
    }

    // Reconnect the stream to actual output
    this.stream = this.context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    this.stream.connect(this.context.destination);

    this.recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, {
      mimeType: "audio/webm",
    });

    this.recorder.onstop = () => {
      stream.getAudioTracks()[0].stop();
      this.callback([...this.chunks]);

      setTimeout(() => {
        this.chunks = [];
      });

      this.active = false;
    };

    this.recorder.ondataavailable = (event) => this.chunks.push(event.data);

    this.active = true;
    this.recorder.start();
  }

  stop() {
    if (!this.active) {
      throw new Error("recorder is already stop");
    } else {
      this.recorder.stop();
    }
  }
}

let rec = new Recorder(async (chunks) => {
//using chunks then to get the stream
});

chrome.tabCapture.capture(
    {
      audio: true,
      video: false,
    },
    function (stream) {
        rec.start(stream);
    })
```

Sorry for lack of details, but I believe when you start an audio capture it disconnects the stream from the default output (speakers). By creating a secondary `MediaStreamSource` and connecting it to the default output (`AudioContext.destination`) you can allow the stream to continue outputting to speakers while being input to your recorder.

---

**Sources**

[MDN: AudioContext](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext)

[MDN: MediaStreamSource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamAudioSourceNode)

[Chrome extension I made 2 years ago](https://github.com/Douile/Chrome-Audio-Visualizer/blob/master/js/audioCapture.js)