# chrome.tabCapture.capture() auto mute my tab sound and recorded video has no sound

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

When I use `chrome.tabCapture.capture({audio : true, video : true})` for recording tab It mutes my tab sound and recorded video has no sound .The same code works in another pc but I don't know what the problem is.

chrome: Version 87.0.4280.88 (Official Build) (64-bit)

OS: Microsoft Windows 10 Pro Version10.0.17763 Build 17763

When I use extensions from chrome web store I have the same problem

Answer (score 3):

When you start an audio capture it disconnects the stream from the default output (speakers). By creating a secondary MediaStreamSource and connecting it to the default output (AudioContext.destination) you can allow the stream to continue outputting to speakers while being input to your recorder.

```
var constraints = {
    audio: true,
    video: true,
  };
  var context = new AudioContext();

  chrome.tabCapture.capture(constraints, function (stream) {
    if (stream) {
      context.createMediaStreamSource(stream).connect(context.destination);
      .......
    }
  }
```

[Refer to this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62321756/original-audio-of-tab-gets-muted-while-using-chrome-tabcapture-capture-and-med)