# Properly using chrome.tabCapture in a manifest v3 extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, web-mediarecorder

**Edit:**

As the end of the year and the end of Manifest V2 is approaching I did a bit more research on this and found the following workarounds:

- The example here that uses the `desktopCapture` API:
  https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-extensions-samples/issues/627

  The problem with this approach is that it requires the user to select a capture source via some UI which can be disruptive. The `--auto-select-desktop-capture-source` command line switch can apparently be used to bypass this but I haven't been able to use it with success.
- The example extension here that works around `tabCapture` not working in
  service workers by creating its own *inactive* tab from
  which to access the `tabCapture` API and record the currently
  *active* tab:

  https://github.com/zhw2590582/chrome-audio-capture

  So far this seems to be the best solution I've found so far in terms of UX. The background page provided in Manifest V2 is essentially replaced with a phantom tab.

The roundaboutedness of the second solution also seems to suggest that the `tabCapture` API is essentially not intended for use in Manifest V3, or else there would have been a more straightforward way to use it. I am disappointed that Manifest V3 is being enforced while essentially leaving behind Manifest V2 features such as this one.

**Original Post:**

I'm trying to write a manifest v3 Chrome extension that captures tab audio. However as far as I can tell, with manifest v3 there are some changes that make this a bit difficult:

- Background scripts are replaced by service workers.
- Service workers do not have access to the `chrome.tabCapture` API.

Despite this I managed to get something that nearly works as popup scripts still have access to `chrome.tabCapture`. However, there is a drawback - the audio of the tab is muted and there doesn't seem to be a way to unmute it. This is what I have so far:

1. Query the service worker current tab from the popup script.

```
let tabId;

// Fetch tab immediately
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({command: 'query-active-tab'}, (response) => {
    tabId = response.id;
});
```

This is the service worker, which response with the current tab ID.

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    (request, sender, sendResponse) => {
        // Popup asks for current tab
        if (request.command === 'query-active-tab') {
            chrome.tabs.query({active: true}, (tabs) => {
                if (tabs.length > 0) {
                    sendResponse({id: tabs[0].id});
                }
            });

            return true;
        }
        ...
```

2. Again in the popup script, from a keyboard shortcut command, use `chrome.tabCapture.getMediaStreamId` to get a media stream ID to be consumed by the current tab, and send that stream ID back to the service worker.

```
// On command, get the stream ID and forward it back to the service worker
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener((command) => {
    chrome.tabCapture.getMediaStreamId({consumerTabId: tabId}, (streamId) => {
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
            command: 'tab-media-stream',
            tabId: tabId,
            streamId: streamId
        })
    });
});
```

4. The service worker forwards that stream ID to the content script.

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    (request, sender, sendResponse) => {
        ...
        // Popup sent back media stream ID, forward it to the content script
        if (request.command === 'tab-media-stream') {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(request.tabId, {
                command: 'tab-media-stream',
                streamId: request.streamId
            });
        }
    }
);
```

5. The content script uses `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` to get the stream.

```
// Service worker sent us the stream ID, use it to get the stream
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        video: false,
        audio: true,
        audio: {
            mandatory: {
                chromeMediaSource: 'tab',
                chromeMediaSourceId: request.streamId
            }
        }
    })
    .then((stream) => {
        // Once we're here, the audio in the tab is muted
        // However, recording the audio works!
        const recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
        const chunks = [];
        recorder.ondataavailable = (e) => {
            chunks.push(e.data);
        };
        recorder.onstop = (e) => saveToFile(new Blob(chunks), "test.wav");
        recorder.start();
        setTimeout(() => recorder.stop(), 5000);
    });
});
```

Here is the code that implements the above: https://github.com/killergerbah/-test-tab-capture-extension

This actually does produce a `MediaStream`, but the drawback is that the sound of the tab is muted. I've tried playing the stream through an audio element, but that seems to do nothing.

*Is there a way to obtain a stream of the tab audio in a manifest v3 extension without muting the audio in the tab?*

I suspect that this approach might be completely wrong as it's so roundabout, but this is the best I could come up with after reading through the docs and various StackOverflow posts.
I've also read that the `tabCapture` API is going to be moved for manifest v3 at some point, so maybe the question doesn't even make sense to ask - however if there is a way to still properly use it I would like to know.

Comment: Any progress updates here? I'm also struggling to use chrome.tabCapture in a v3 extension @R-J

Comment: @lsimmons I haven't made any progress on using tapCapture in manifest v3 - I ended up downgrading to manifest v2. I still need to explore the answer below however.

Comment: After hunting around I found this bug which is still open: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1214847

Comment: I drop this comment here since it seems to be the most recent relevant topic. In Manifest v3 it's recommended to use an offscreen document to solve this problem. [Read more here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/how-to/web-platform/screen-capture).

Answer (score 1):

I found your post very useful in progressing my implementation of an audio tab recorder.

Regarding the specific muting issue you were running into, I resolved it by looking here: [Original audio of tab gets muted while using chrome.tabCapture.capture() and MediaRecorder()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62321756/original-audio-of-tab-gets-muted-while-using-chrome-tabcapture-capture-and-med)

```
// Service worker sent us the stream ID, use it to get the stream
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        video: false,
        audio: true,
        audio: {
            mandatory: {
                chromeMediaSource: 'tab',
                chromeMediaSourceId: request.streamId
            }
        }
    })
    .then((stream) => {
        // To resolve original audio muting
        context = new AudioContext();
        var audio = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
        audio.connect(context.destination);

        const recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
        const chunks = [];
        recorder.ondataavailable = (e) => {
            chunks.push(e.data);
        };
        recorder.onstop = (e) => saveToFile(new Blob(chunks), "test.wav");
        recorder.start();
        setTimeout(() => recorder.stop(), 5000);
    });
});
```

Comment: Good to hear you can get it working. As mentioned in my reply just now to my original post, there is also a bug for tabCapture missing: bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1214847

Comment: audio:true is redundent here...

Answer (score 0):

This may not be exactly what you are looking for, but perhaps it may provide some insight.

> I've tried playing the stream through an audio element, but that seems to do nothing.

Ironically this is how I managed to get around the issue; by creating an  object in the popup itself. When using tabCapture in the popup script, it returns the stream, and I set the audio srcObject to that stream.

HTML:
`<audio id="audioObject" autoplay> No source detected </audio>`

JS:

```
chrome.tabCapture.capture({audio: true, video: false}, function(stream) {
    var audio = document.getElementById("audioObject");
    audio.srcObject = stream
})
```

According to [this post](https://cezaraugusto.net/posts/what-changes-in-chrome-extension-manifest-v3/) on Manifest V3, chrome.capture will be the new namespace for tabCapture and the like, but I haven't seen anything beyond that.

Comment: I also read the post you've linked to re: chrome.tabCapture being moved to the chrome.capture namespace.  But in practice, it still appears to be under chrome.tabCapture in MV3.  I'm guessing the namespace change never occurred, or has been delayed.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, and I resolve it by using Web Audio API. Just create a new context and conect it to a media stream source using the captures MediaStream, this is an example:

```
avoidSilenceInTab: (desktopStream: MediaStream) => {
 var contextTab = new AudioContext();
 contextTab
   .createMediaStreamSource(desktopStream)
   .connect(contextTab.destination);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Mute issue is resolved with

```
const media = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);

// Continue to play the captured audio to the user.
const output = new AudioContext();
const source = output.createMediaStreamSource(media);
source.connect(output.destination);
```

From official [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/screen_capture/#audio-and-video-offscreen-doc)